# How can I programmatically grab a photo matching a tag/keyword?

Tags: fetch, photo, flickr

I am trying to display a photo each time a user takes an action, and I'd like it to be relevant to a certain keyword, such as a city, artist, or music venue.

I see that flickr has an api:
https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html

One thing missing from that is the ability to filter for only creative commons licenses.

The Whisper mobile app does a pretty good job of grabbing a relevant photo, so one question I have is how they might be doing it?

Another is whether there are any services that specialize in this?

(first post, searched as best as I could, apologizing in advance if this is a n00b question in some way, and thanks for any help you can offer)

Answer (score 0):

Try the `license` parameter of the search API.  From the docs:

> The license id for photos (for possible values see the [flickr.photos.licenses.getInfo](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.licenses.getInfo.html) method). Multiple licenses may be comma-separated.

Creative Commons 2.0 licenses are coded with values 1 through 6.